# How to parcel class object that contains hash map? Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass a custom array list from one activity to another using  `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra`.

So I implemented `Parcelable` in my class object:

```
class AudioModel(audioTitle:String,map:HashMap<String, Any>):Parcelable{

    var title:String=""
    var artistName:String=""
    var urlLink:String=""

    init{
        title=audioTitle
        urlLink=map["url"].toString()
        artistName=map["artist"].toString()
    }
}
```

and after adding parcelable implementation, I have:

```
class AudioModel(audioTitle: String, map: HashMap<String, Any>) : Parcelable {

    var title: String = ""
    var artistName: String = ""
    var urlLink: String = ""

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            TODO("audioTitle"),
            TODO("map")) {
        title = parcel.readString()
        artistName = parcel.readString()
        urlLink = parcel.readString()
    }

    init {
        title = audioTitle
        urlLink = map["url"].toString()
        artistName = map["artist"].toString()
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(title)
        parcel.writeString(artistName)
        parcel.writeString(urlLink)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<AudioModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): AudioModel {
            return AudioModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<AudioModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that I'm getting warning at constructor with

> unreachable code message

and because of that I can't pass my data using  `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually just fine. It's just that the TODO doesn't work in this case. Replace the TODO's with actual code and it should work.

For example:

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            hashMapOf<String, Any>()) {
```